# complex lists within linq queries with select

Tags: vb.net, linq, select

I have following linq to entities query, it looks good for compilation but giving me the following error when I run the code. And I want to get a very complex object, which is having some list of derived objects from EDM models. The lists in the below class are not directly from EDM models but they are derived classes from EDM to add more complexity to my problem. Here is the error message. Please help me in resolving this query. I have to get all the data that I want in one linq query thats what my lead is asking me for earlier I had one query for each component and I was adding them. But lead wants it in one query. Please help me in any ways link or code snippet or any suggestion please.

```
LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LNI.WSAW.External.StayAtWork.EmployerAddress] ToList[EmployerAddress](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[LNI.WSAW.External.StayAtWork.EmployerAddress])' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.
```

And Here is the code:

```
            Dim _requestrecord = (From r In Context.Requests.Include("Claims").Include("Employers").Include("EmployerContacts")
                                 Where r.RequestId = RequestId AndAlso r.ManualClaimFlag = ManualClaim
            Join c In Context.Claims On r.ClaimId Equals c.ClaimId Where c.ClaimNo.Equals(ClaimNumber)
            Join e In Context.Employers On r.Employer.EmployerId Equals e.EmployerId Where e.EmplAccntNo.Equals(EmployerAccountNumber)
            Join ec In Context.EmployerContacts On r.EmployerContactId Equals ec.EmployerContactId Where ec.SawGuid.Equals(EmployerContactGuid)
            Select New RequestRecord() With { _
            .Addresses = (From at In Context.EmployerAddressTypes
                              Join ea In Context.EmployerAddresses On at.AddressTypeId Equals ea.EmployerAddressType.AddressTypeId Where ea.EmployerId = r.Employer.EmployerId
                              Select New External.StayAtWork.EmployerAddress() With { _
                             .AddressLn1 = ea.AddressLn1,
                             .AddressLn2 = ea.AddressLn2,
                             .AddressLn3 = ea.AddressLn3,
                             .AddressType = at.Description,
                             .BusLocAddressId = ea.BuslocId,
                             .City = ea.City,
                             .Country = ea.Country,
                             .NewSwAddress = ea.NewSwAddressFlag,
                             .State = ea.St,
                             .Zip = ea.Zip,
                             .ZipExt = ea.ZipExt
                             }).ToList(),
            .Employer = New EmployerBaisc() With { _
                .EmployerId = e.EmployerId,
                .EmployerName = e.EmplName
                    },
            .Exspenses = (From td In Context.TransactionDates Where td.RequestId = RequestId
                              Join ex In Context.ExpenseTransactions On ex.TransactionDateId Equals td.TransactionDateId
                              Select New External.StayAtWork.RequestExpense() With { _
                             .ExpenseAmount = ex.ExpenseAmount,
                             .ExpenseDate = ex.TransactionDate.TransactionDt.ToString(),
                             .ExpenseItem = ex.ExpenseItem,
                             .ExpenseReason = ex.ExpenseReason,
                             .ExpenseType = ex.ExpenseSubTypeId
                             }).ToList(),
            .Wages = (From td In Context.TransactionDates Where td.RequestId = RequestId
                              Join wt In Context.WageTransactions On wt.TransactionDateId Equals td.TransactionDateId
                              Select New External.StayAtWork.RequestWage() With { _
                             .DailyWage = wt.DailyWagePaidAmount,
                             .WorkDate = wt.TransactionDate.TransactionDt.ToString(),
                             .WorkHours = wt.WorkHours.ToString()
                             }).ToList(),
            .Timeloss = (From ctl In Context.ClaimTimelosses
                              Join clms In Context.Claims On ctl.ClaimId Equals clms.ClaimId Where clms.ClaimId = c.ClaimId
                              Select New External.StayAtWork.ClaimTimeLoss() With { _
                             .ClaimNo = ctl.Claim.ClaimNo,
                             .FromDate = ctl.FromDt.ToString(),
                             .ToDate = ctl.ToDt.ToString()
                             }).ToList(),
            .Files = (From rfs In Context.RequestFiles
                              Join reqs In Context.Requests On rfs.RequestId Equals reqs.RequestId Where reqs.RequestId = RequestId
                              Select New FileBasic() With { _
                             .FileId = rfs.RequestFileId,
                             .FileName = rfs.FileName,
                             .FromDiv = rfs.FromDiv
                             }).ToList(),
            .UiSettings = (From ruis In Context.RequestUis
                              Join reqs In Context.Requests On ruis.RequestId Equals reqs.RequestId Where reqs.RequestId = RequestId
                              Select New External.StayAtWork.RequestUI() With { _
                             .ApfByFax = ruis.ApfByFaxFlag,
                             .ApfByMail = ruis.ApfByMailFlag,
                             .ApfLniHas = ruis.ApfLniHasFlag,
                             .ExpenseByFax = ruis.ExpenseByFaxFlag,
                             .ExpenseByMail = ruis.ExpenseByMailFlag,
                             .ExpenseLniHas = ruis.ExpenseLniHasFlag,
                             .JobByFax = ruis.JobByFaxFlag,
                             .JobByLni = ruis.JobByLniFlag,
                             .JobByMail = ruis.JobByMailFlag,
                             .LastDiv = ruis.LastDiv,
                             .requestId = ruis.RequestId,
                             .WageByFax = ruis.WageByFaxFlag,
                             .WageByMail = ruis.WageByMailFlag,
                             .WageLniHas = ruis.WageLniHasFlag
                             }).FirstOrDefault(),
            .Request = New RequestBasic() With { _
                .RequestId = RequestId,
                .Comments = r.Comments,
                .InjuredWorkerName = c.WorkerName,
                .IsFixedSalary = r.FixedSalaryFlag,
                .IsGraveyard = r.GraveyardFlag,
                .IsManualClaim = r.ManualClaimFlag,
                .JobDescriptBeforeInjury = r.JobDescriptBefore,
                .JobDescriptLightDuty = r.JobDescriptLightduty,
                .TrackHoursFlag = r.HoursTrackedFlag
                }
            }).FirstOrDefault()
```

```
        Response.ResultData = _requestrecord
```

And here is the the class that I have to get:
    
    Public Class RequestRecord

```
    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Request As RequestBasic

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Employer As EmployerBaisc

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Addresses As List(Of EmployerAddress)

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Timeloss As List(Of ClaimTimeLoss)

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Wages As List(Of RequestWage)

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Exspenses As List(Of RequestExpense)

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property Files As List(Of FileBasic)

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property PaidDates As List(Of PaidDate)

    <DataMember()>
    Public Property UiSettings As RequestUI

End Class
```

Thanks in advance.